# Can I deploy my ASP.NET MVC 4 application in .net 4

Tags: c#, .net, hosting, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know about a thing that IS ASP.NET MVC 4 application can be run on .NET 4 server.

I am trying to deploy my MVC4 application and I am got the error that.

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I target the .net 4 framework but I am still having this error. I am not sure what happen to server. I am trying to look on other post but I did not find any post who can clearify that MVC 4 can run on .net server.

Comment: What do you mean by ".NET 4 server"? Are you trying to run this in a homemade server app, instead of doing the normal thing and running it in IIS?

Comment: @JoeWhite Means Window based server who have .net 4 application can work also able to run MVC 4. Please edit my question if It's make a confusion.

Comment: The 500 error could mean just about any error... Can you look in the eventlog of the server?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Actually I got a server from someone help to test my own scripts. I have installed in subdomain / dierectory.

Comment: Is MVC4 installed on the server? If not you will need to bin deploy by following the instructions here http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx. This is for MVC3 but I think it should be the same for 4. Also, would be helpful if you posted the stack trace.

Comment: No it's not. I am trying to get deployed directly by copy the source on server.

Comment: Would you please advise the full error message that you get from the server? 500 internal server error means a lot. Do you host by your own server or with hosting provider? Could you please kindly check that ASP.NET MVC 3 has been configured correctly?

Comment: I ran into the same issue-- there is nothing in the event log nor is there a stack trace. This only impacts the ApiController

Answer (score 32):

Yes. ASP.Net MVC 4 will run on ASP.Net 4 and ASP.Net 4.5. I am running a site on ASP.Net 4, and it is also confirmed in [this blog post by Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/19/asp-net-mvc-4-beta.aspx). This assumes that you are not targeting any new 4.5 features in your application.

Be sure that you are copying the required MVC 4 .dll files in your bin folder if the server does not already have them installed. [This post by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) explains how to bin deploy version 3. [Hanselman has a similar article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx). You will need to check [the version 4 release notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806) for the current .dlls required.

We may be able to provide a more specific answer if you can provide some additional details, and let us know what version of IIS and Visual Studio you are running.

Comment: There are NuGet packages that do the leg work for you now, right?

Answer (score 5):

1. Right click your mvc4/webapi project ,choose the "Add Library Package Reference..." item, checked the "ASP.NET MVC" checkbox .
2. Install DotNet Framework 4 Client Profile on your server.Because of the reference item "System.Net.Http" target framework is .net4 client profile.
3. Publish your mvc4 project to your server
4. enjoy......:)_

Answer (score 2):

> Razor 2 is part of the next wave of the WebPages/MVC framework so it
>   will require MVC4. There's nothing stopping you from using our
>   Open-Source code to wedge Razor 2 in to MVC3, but it isn't a supported
>   scenario.
>
> **Remember that MVC 4 works on .NET 4.0 and does NOT require .NET 4.5!**

[ASP.net mvc programmer blog](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/13/what-else-is-new-in-razor-v2.html/)

Comment: no it doesn't require 4.5, until you use 4.5 features like bundling/async/await, then you bomb out : )

Comment: @AdamTuliper, o.k. but it's not just mvc4... you can't use async without 4.5, it has nothing to do with asp.net or asp.net-mvc-4

Comment: Sure it does - async is used in mvc4 source so it has to do both with mvc4 and .net 4.5, but we both know the end result though- if you want that, you clearly need 4.5, if not you are good to go. .

Comment: FYI, async is still available in MVC4+.NET4.0 if you reference the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) NuGet package. (VS2012 is required, though)