# MVC 4 web application on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7

I am novice to MVC4. I was using .net framework 3.5 for my web-application and was hosted on IIS 7. Recently we have decided to move on MVC. We have converted our web-application to MVC and on ASP.NET development server it is working fine. Then we deployed it on IIS 7 but not working.

Do we need to install .NET Framework or something to that machine / sever?

Comment: You need to install ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Will it be installed automatically if I install .NET Framework 4.5?

Comment: Probably not. As far as I know it's still not part of framework installation.

Comment: You have to install it manually. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992651/is-mvc4-baked-into-net-4-5

Answer (score 0):

YOu are missing ASP.NET MVC libriaries. You have two options:

1. Install ASP.NET MVC on your server
2. Deploy required binaries with your application (see more on [Scott Hanselman blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx))

Comment: What if I install .NET Framework 4.5 on Server / Machine? Will MVC be installed automatically with it?

Comment: MVC is not included with .NET Framework 4.5. To make your life easier going forward, make sure that you add *all* the MVC dependencies as NU Get packages to the web project. The easiest way to do this is to create a new MVC project, and then look at the `packages.config` file and install the packages named `Microsoft.AspNet.*` to your own project. It might be enough to just run `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` from the Package Manager Console. This will allow you to easily upgrade when the next version of MVC launches.